# resize image with aspect ratio 4:3 to 16:9 without losing the responsive behaviour with css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Suppose that I have this image (640x480) in 4:3 aspect ratio:

[image]

And the code to show it is:

`<img src="../static/images/image4-3.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">`

What I want is to show it in 16:9 (the real aspect ratio of that image, the dimensions are 640x360):

[image]

Is obvious that doing 16/9=1.77777777778 => 640/1.77777777778 = 360. So if set an style for "height: 360px" and "width: 100%" it works, but, it's not responsive, there is a way to edit the height of an image (dinamically) and mantain the responsive behaviour given by bootstrap?

By the way, I'm really new to CSS, so maybe this is an stupid quesiton.

Comment: set `aspect-ratio` instead of `height`...

Comment: @RenevanderLende its worth noting that `aspect-ratio` browser support is relatively new, see [`Can I Use`](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_aspect-ratio).

Comment: Why is your 16:9 image stored in a 4:3 image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `Bootstrap` has buil-in helpers to apply ratio to your elements, you may use those built-in helpers that will allow you to have the ratio you want along with keeping things responsive. To do so:

1. wrap your image in a `div`
2. apply `ratio ratio-16x9` classes to that `div`. Those classes will make that `div` a responsive `16/9` container.
3. apply `img-fluid` to the image so that it scales nicely with its container.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- note the "ratio ratio-16x9" classes on the parent div -->

<!-- resize the screen to see how the image nicely scales while maintaining the desired ratio -->

<!-- for demo purpose, am setting the width of the wrapper div to 75% so that the ratio effect can be easily seen -->
<div class="ratio ratio-16x9 w-75 m-auto">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4xRM.jpg" class="img-fluid">
</div>
```

> Learn more about [`Bootsrap 5 Ratio Helpers`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/helpers/ratio/) on `BS5` docs.

> It is worth noting that there is a native way to apply `ratio`s using [`aspect-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio) rule but that later rule still (at the time of writing) doesn't have a good browser support.